# Can a .net standard project have a .nuspec file?

Tags: nuget, nuspec, .net-standard-2.1

I developed a `.net standard 2.1` project with the intention of publishing it as a nuget, and I published it correctly.

The only thing I wanted to know is if in my project I can add a `.nuspec` file, because I tried to add it but when I do the build (which also generates the nuget package) it seems not to take the metadata information added in the .nuspec file.
On the other hand, adding a `PropertyGroup` with similar properties in my project's `.csproj` file, when I build the package takes the metadata I entered.

I wanted to know if there is a way that I can "include" my .nuspec configurations when I build the project.
I found a few more questions where they recommended calling the `.nuspec` exactly like the project but in my case it doesn't seem to have worked.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've got an SDK style project then it's recommended not to use a nuspec, and to keep all the package metadata in your project file instead https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#project-type-compatibility

You can still use one if you really want to though https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#packing-using-a-nuspec-file

Sample command lines:

```
dotnet pack <path to .csproj file> -p:NuspecFile=<path to nuspec file> -p:NuspecProperties=<> -p:NuspecBasePath=<Base path>
```

or

```
msbuild -t:pack <path to .csproj file> -p:NuspecFile=<path to nuspec file> -p:NuspecProperties=<> -p:NuspecBasePath=<Base path>
```

Comment: In fact my question should have been whether it was better to use nuspec or keep metadata in the project file. Thank you very much, doubt solved!